# Automatically create LDAP groups for each new system user according to its username

Tags: linux, ldap, samba, openldap

is there any way to set and create a default group for each newly created system user so he belongs to its own user group?

I mean, when a create a `user foo` i would like to create automatically a `group foo` also adding this user to his `default foo` group.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Why? It's a strange requirement. You already have the user entry, why do you think you need two? And a user isn't a group. Who are the other members going to be, other than himself? And if none, what use is a group with only one member? This is sounding like an XY problem.

Comment: Here's a link which may help you understand the GNU/Linux Users and Groups basics http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/36845/the-beginners-guide-to-managing-users-and-groups-in-linux/